# Can I use SMPS to power 12V DC water pump

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, dc-motor, 12v

I'm looking to use a 12V 60W DC water pump in my project, and I'm trying to find a suitable way to supply power for the pump. I'm wary about using the brick-like power adapters as I think they are not reliable. I see that SMPS is more reliable. Can I use a 12V 10A SMPS unit to power the pump ? One concern is that I read that a DC motor could draw upto 3 times more current while starting. So the SMPS could cut-off supply due to overload. Please note, I will be turning the pump on/off many times in day using arduino/relay control.

Water pump - 
http://www.ebay.in/itm/12V-High-Pressure-Auto-Diaphragm-Water-Pump-5L-min-100-PSI-Pressure-Switch-/222221212173?

SMPS -
http://www.ebay.in/itm/12V-10A-120-Watt-DC-Switch-Mode-Power-Supply-Driver-Transformer-CCTV-Led-Strips-/322280796678?hash=item4b096eb206:g:aqwAAOSw6n5Xwt4s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's *probably* adequate. The pump draws 60W continuous, which is 5A, according to the nameplate, and you are proposing a 10A power supply.

Diaphragm pumps, to my knowledge, do not tend to draw enormous current on start-up, and the power supply, if the ratings are real, is capable of supplying some startup surge, so a 2:1 factor is probably okay.

The only way to be sure, really, is to test it. You could also go for a much bigger power supply to be more sure.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I use SMPS to power 12V DC water pump

Yes.

> I'm wary about using the brick-like power adapters as I think they are not reliable. I see that SMPS is more reliable.

Most of these power supplies are SMPS. You've got some misunderstanding there.

> One concern is that I read that a DC motor could draw upto 3 times more current while starting.

Depending on the motor, a limitation of how much overcurrent the power supply can source might or might not be a problem. For pumps, I'd expect the motor not to need overly much turn-on current, because there's most likely not much mechanical torque that needs to be generated to get the motor started. But: without knowing how exactly your pump motor works, this is all speculation.

As a general hint: if you need reliability, I don't think "the thing I found on ebay looks fine, I'll go ask electronics.stackexchange.com whether it'll work" is a good idea.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is first time i'm asking a question in this forum, I gave the product links as a reference so that the tech specs may help in answering. Probably I should mention any relevant technical parameters in the question itself.

Comment: There's absolutely nothing wrong with linking to the product in question! but you're right, adding specs to a question is a good idea :) my point is that if you're worried about reliability, some unknown seller on ebay is probably not your source of choice for components!